# MongoDB Group by with summation of all columns

Tags: mongodb

Sample Input:

```
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "team": "a",
    "score": 200
  },
  {
    "_id": 2,
    "team": "a",
    "score": 200
  },
  {
    "_id": 3,
    "team": "b",
    "score": 700
  },
  {
    "_id": 4,
    "team": "c",
    "score": 100
  }
]
```

From the above data I am trying to get summation of all `score` columns along with doing a group by on `team`.

In the sample input team a has 2 records but during calculation I need to take only 1 of the records (basically groupby on team).

So my final output should be `200 + 700 + 100 = 1000`

I have tried with below query but I could not get desired output.

```
db.games.aggregate([ { 
$group: { 
    "_id": "$team",
    score : { $first: '$score' },
    total: { $sum: "$score" } 
}
}])
```

and output as

```
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "c",
            "score" : 100,
            "total" : 100
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "b",
            "score" : 700,
            "total" : 700
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "a",
            "score" : 200,
            "total" : 400
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1.0000000000000000
}
```

Comment: So why dont you just do a `{$sum: 1}` on the scores?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could do something like this:

```
db.names.aggregate([
        {$group:{_id:"$team", score: {$first:"$score"}}}, 
        {$group:{_id:"", sum: {$sum:"$score"}}}]);
```